# Confusion related to operator precedence

Tags: java, compiler-errors, boolean, runtime, operator-precedence

```
public class A{
    public static void main(){
        boolean result = true || 3 < 5/0 && false;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I compiled this program. It compiled perfectly as expected. But when I ran this program it gave an output-

```
true
```

Well, this thing bothers me as it is evident that division(/) operator has highest precedence. Then comes the less than(<) operator, then comes AND(&&) operator and then comes OR(||) operator. So according to me the first step that should be followed is as follows -

```
true || 3 < (5/0) && false
```

And at this point itself it should raise the Exception. But this doesn't happen. Well I think the computer evaluated this expression as follows -

```
(true) || 3 < 5/0 && false
```

And then it didn't see the need to evaluate the right side of || because of short circuit evaluation. But || has the least precedence among these!! Can someone explain that how this expression gets executed step by step and also how the precedence of && is more than ||. I would be grateful. Thanks for reading till here :)

Comment: `&&` has a higher priority than `||`: `(true || ((3 < 5/0) && false))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24

> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

In your case the left-hand operand is `true`, so obviously the right-hand operand is not evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

your code is a short circuit equivalent to

```
System.out.println(true);
```

because if you dont group condition then it will be automatically grouped as

```
 boolean result = true || ((3 < (5 / 0)) && false);
```

making the right side of the condition actually dead code... not even evaluated (that is why you dont event get the ***ArithmeticException*** when div by zero)

Answer (score 0):

```
true || ((3 < (5 / 0)) && false);
```

Right-hand side of the `OR` operator will only be calculated if the LHR is calculated to false else result variable will be assigned as true.

So in your case `3 < 5/0 && false` never gets calculated.

Answer (score 0):

In here java execute this logic sequential. 
execute true || 3 < 5/0 then result with this && false.

Since you use || before and first argument is true its not check for other conditions.

you can test by modify your code as below.

```
public class A{
    public static void main(){
        boolean result = true || toOperaion() && false;
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static boolean toOperaion() {
        System.out.println("In Operation");
        return 3 < 5 / 0;
    }
}
```